# How to link to google chromes downloads page from html?

Tags: html, google-chrome, hyperlink

I am making my own personal homepage for my chrome web browser. I want to add a link on this page to go to my downloads page. Such as if I were to hit ctrl+j or just type in "chrome://downloads" in my address bar. I have a link set up and I set the href attribute to "chrome://downloads" but it will not open. It does nothing at all.

Before anyone says to search for an answer, I have been searching for about an hour now.

example of my link:

```
<a href="chrome://downloads" target="_blank">Downloads</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome isn't allowing this for security reasons.

The JavaScript console says:

[image]

a JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/De78E/).

It's unlikely that there is a workaround, although you could try having the file on a local `file:///` URL and seeing whether the restrictions are less strict there.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I would upvote it but because I am new I cannot.

Comment: Sure, no problem. You can mark it "accepted" (after a couple minutes I think), but that's purely optional.

Comment: @user3084715 But you can accept it as your answer by checking the tick mark right below the vote count shown in left side of the answer